# Else without if?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I was working on my assignment for my Java 1 class and I am getting an error that does not seem like it should be one. Can I get some help? It is saying that I have an else w/out if.

here is the if block

```
char placement = scan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                      if(placement == 'F')
                      {
                          System.out.print("Please Enter The Show To Be Added At The Beginning Of The List: ");
                          String show = scan.next();
                          TVShows.add(0, show);
                      }
                      else if(placement == 'R');
                      {
                          System.out.print("Please Enter The Show To Be Added At The End Of The List");
                          String show = scan.next();
                          TVShows.add(show);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          System.out.println("Invalid Choice Please Try Again");
                      }
```

Comment: What is the error? Paste the exact error, including line numbers. Then tell us what's at the line number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the semi colon

```
else if (placement == 'R');
                          ^
```

which is terminating the `else if` block statement

Comment: Thank you it usally is those damn semicolons or a comma